# Android: getHolder().setFixedSize(1920,1080) causes Issue with screen Resolution

Tags: java, android, canvas, resolution

Im developing a Game. I want my screen to always be 1920x1080.

```
getHolder().setFixedSize(1920,1080);
```

setFixedSize on my SurfaceView achieves this. It also creates a problem, however: the screen is still in WQHD res instead of  also being FHD. This leads to mouseclickposition being bigger than the canvas is visually, and thus clicking on buttons no longer works unless I press where they actually would be in the smaller resolution.

Is there a way to set Android's resolution to 1920x1080? Maybe setting the Layout to that? I also tried making my canvas equal to a bitmap thats the right dimensions but that doesnt seem to change Anything at all.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10,100,null);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

An alternative way to solve this might be to calculate the corresponding mouseClick Position from the bigger screen to the smaller, I suppose, but that seems like the suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solved it

```
public static float normalize(float value, float min, float max) {
        return Math.abs((value - min) / (max - min));
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int differenceInWidth = actualScreenwidth - screenwidth; //2560-1920

        float xPercent =  normalize(event.getX(),0,actualScreenwidth);
        Log.d("mouse_P_xPercent", Float.toString(xPercent));
        float yPercent =  normalize(event.getY(),0,actualScreenheight);
        Log.d("mouse_P_yPercent", Float.toString(yPercent));


        mouseCurrentPositionX = (int) (screenwidth*xPercent);
        mouseCurrentPositionY = (int) (screenheight*xPercent);
```